# To Create Audit Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, audit

From this Below code

1. I need `OldValue` and `NewValue` in XML format
2. In `@PKSelect` string values should be like 'Mumbai' with quotes
3. Concat `@PKFieldSelect` and `@PKValueSelect` In `@PKSelect`

pls suggest me to do above question

```
create TRIGGER auditrg ON [tablename] FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS

DECLARE 
       @TableName VARCHAR(128) ,
       @PKCols VARCHAR(1000) ,
       @sql VARCHAR(2000), 
       @UpdateDate VARCHAR(21) ,
       @UserName VARCHAR(128) ,
       @Type CHAR(1) ,
       @PKSelect nVARCHAR(max),
       @OldValue nVARCHAR(max),
       @NewValue nVARCHAR(max),
       @PKFieldSelect nVARCHAR(max),
       @PKValueSelect nVARCHAR(max)
begin
--You will need to change @TableName to match the table to be audited
SELECT @TableName = 'tablename'
SELECT @UserName = SYSTEM_USER ,
       @UpdateDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)+ ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 114)

-- Action
      IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
       IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
               SELECT @Type = 'U'
        ELSE
               SELECT @Type = 'I'
        ELSE
               SELECT @Type = 'D'              

    SET @OldValue = (SELECT * FROM DELETED  FOR XML AUTO,BINARY BASE64)  
    SET @NewValue = (SELECT * FROM INSERTED  FOR XML AUTO,BINARY BASE64)

-- get list of columns

SELECT * INTO #ins FROM inserted 
SELECT * INTO #del FROM deleted


SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
-- Get primary key columns for full outer join
SELECT @PKCols = COALESCE(@PKCols + ' and', ' on') 
               + ' i.' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ' = d.' + c.COLUMN_NAME
       FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,
              INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
       WHERE   pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
       AND     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
       AND     c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
       AND     c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME 

-- Get primary key fields select for insert       
SELECT @PKFieldSelect = COALESCE(@PKFieldSelect+'+','') 
       + '''' + COLUMN_NAME +''''
       FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,
               INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
       WHERE   pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
       AND     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
       AND     c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
       AND     c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME  

select @PKValueSelect = coalesce(@PKValueSelect+'+','') + 'convert(varchar(100), coalesce(i.' + COLUMN_NAME + ',d.' + COLUMN_NAME + '))'
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
where pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
and CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
and c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
and c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

SET @PKSelect = (SELECT CAST(@PKFieldSelect AS varchar(100)) + ' ' + CAST(@PKValueSelect AS varchar(100)))
exec sp_executesql @PKSelect 
print(@PKSelect)


--SELECT @PKSelect = @PKFieldSelect + @PKValueSelect


IF @PKCols IS NULL
BEGIN
       RAISERROR('no PK on table %s', 16, -1, @TableName)
       RETURN
END

select @sql='insert  Audit (Type,TableName,PK,OldValue,NewValue,UserName,UpdateDate)   
select ''' + @Type + ''',''' 
       + @TableName + ''',' + @PKSelect    
       + ',''' + @OldValue+ ''''
       + ',''' + @NewValue+ ''''
       + ',''' + @UserName + ''''
       + ',''' + @UpdateDate+ ''''
       + ' from #ins i full outer join #del d'
       + @PKCols
               EXEC (@sql)
    END
GO
```

Comment: I'd suggest to put all this into stored proc. If data modification is not very intensive - just execute that proc with table name as parameter and may be those `#inserted` and `#deleted` temp tables. If this processing significantly slows down modification process than probably to write all changes to `audit.MytableChangeLog` table with copy of structure of the original table placed in different filegroup and process it serially with a job.

Comment: can u give me some example

Comment: Example of what mentioned?